# How to write test case for $q.all

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How to write test case for below code in angularjs using jasmine, I have done mock of data which is working fine but not able to mock $q data due to that my test cases getting failed

```
$q.all([_allMasterList, _allUserList]).then(function(arrData){
      $scope.notificationLists = manageNotifications.getAllNotificationList(arrData, _fmno);
    });
```

I tried below

```
beforeEach(function() {
        manageNotifications = jasmine.createSpyObj('manageNotifications', ['getNotificationMasterList', 'getNotificationUserList', 'getAllNotificationList' ]);
    });

  beforeEach(inject(function( $controller, _manageNotifications_, $window, $location, $rootScope, _mckModal_, $timeout, System_Messages, $q, $httpBackend, _confirmationModalService_, _API_ENDPOINT_ ){
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
        API_ENDPOINT = _API_ENDPOINT_;
        manageNotifications = _manageNotifications_;
    confirmationModalService = _confirmationModalService_;

    /* Mock Data */
    manageNotifications.getNotificationMasterList = function(){
            deferred_getNotificationMasterList = $q.defer();
            deferred_getNotificationMasterList.resolve(_masterList);
            return deferred_getNotificationMasterList.promise;
    };

    manageNotifications.getNotificationUserList = function(_data){
            deferred_getNotificationUserList = $q.defer();
            deferred_getNotificationUserList.resolve({
        "status": "Success",
        "dataValue": _data
      });
            return deferred_getNotificationUserList.promise;
    };

  }));
```

Comment: What do you have already?

Answer (score 0):

Promises from AngularJs are tightly bound to the digest cycle. This means that no promises will be resolved or rejected until a digest is being triggered.

Because you are in an unit test environment you need to trigger the digest yourself before doing an assert.

Try calling on your scope one of the following, depending on what you desire:

1. `rootScope.$digest()` - will execute the digest
2. `rootScope.$apply(<some_exprssion>)` - will evaluate an expression that is external of Angular framework (eg: DOM events that when handled need to evaluate some logic in the Angular context)

`$apply` is calling `$digest` and its execution looks like:

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** you can write less

Instead of:

```
manageNotifications.getNotificationMasterList = function(){
        deferred_getNotificationMasterList = $q.defer();
        deferred_getNotificationMasterList.resolve(_masterList);
        return deferred_getNotificationMasterList.promise;
};
```

you can write:

```
manageNotifications.getNotificationMasterList = () => $q.when(_masterList);
```

or better, more Jasmine-like, if you need to spy on your already created objects and customize the mock:

```
spyOn(manageNotifications, 'getNotificationMasterList ').and.returnValue($q.when(_masterList));
```

**Summary:**

Keep up with **AAA**

**Arrange** your test by setting up your mocks.

**Act** by invoking your action/method then call `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply(<expr>)` to trigger the digest.

**Assert** to check what is expected.

You can also consider creating **test fixtures** in order to modularize the Arrange and maybe also the Act part and reuse the logic in more complex testing scenarios where you need to compose multiple steps.